# After calculating word count I am unable to resize the textarea element without CSS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to size it around row=4, col=50. Before I added the JS it was resizing no problem, but since that, it will not resize.

HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Process Form Text</title>

  <script src="process.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Type Your Words In The Text Area Below</h1>

  <textarea id="myText" row="10" col="50" style="text-transform: uppercase" onkeyup="countWords(this);"></textarea>
  <br>
  <span id="wordCount"></span>
  <span id="charCount"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
function countWords(self) {
  var spaces = self.value.match(/\S+/g);
  var words = spaces ? spaces.length : 0;

  document.getElementById("wordCount").innerHTML = words + " words";
}
```

Comment: I have loaded your code into codepen and the textarea is resizing with the cursor and through HTML both with and without JS. Is there any other code you didn't include here that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

> rows="10" cols="50"

Instead of

> row="10" col="50"